# Can I create a table in Athena using only one file of s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

If I provide the complete file name of that file ,is that gonna work?

(aws beginner)

I want to create a table using only one s3 file in Athena. I did so but not getting any data ?  (that file has some data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, specifying the complete object key (aka filename) won't work.

If you read [table location in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html), it says:

> When you specify the LOCATION ... Use a trailing slash.

and:

> Do not use filenames, underscores, wildcards, or glob patterns for specifying file locations.

So, you need to restructure your S3 contents and specify a location ending in /.